# How to create kubernetes configmap from properties file during maven build?

Tags: maven, docker, kubernetes, configmap

We have an old java application which has few properties files. We are doing a POC to deploy it in Kubernetes cluster using Helm chart. As of now, we manually creating configmap by copying the content from properties file. If any updates in properties file, as a result the same update should be done in configmap manually. So, Is there any solution available to create a configmap from the properties file during maven build?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the properties file look like and how do you want the ConfigMap to look like?

Answer (score 2):

If you were using Spring Cloud Config in the past to fetch your properties and reload application during change of properties, there is an alternative provided by Spring for Kubernetes which allows fetching and reading the properties from your ConfigMap(s) directly and allows reload when the ConfigMap changes

Reference - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.1.0.M3/reference/html/#kubernetes-propertysource-implementations

But looks like there is no solution available yet to generate ConfigMap(s) from property file(s) directly during a maven build.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by help of volume and volumeMounts.

You can get info from  [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/configmaps.html)